# Chainlink Multi Variable Responses smart contract request not fulfilled by oracle.sol

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink, toml

I have created an chainlink external adaptor and I have defined a Multi-Word word request job. Now I have created a Multi Variable responses contract (i.e. externalAPIConsumer.sol) for the job but when calling the requestValidationData(), job runs and completes successfully but the transaction fails because oracle.sol contract gives error as follow:

```
Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]
```

Here is externalAPIConsumer.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract ExternalAPIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

    uint256 public allInSystem;
    uint256 public isProject;
    uint256 public senderAuthority;
    uint256 public receiverAuthority;

    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;

    event requestFulfilled(
        uint256 isProject,
        uint256 senderAuthority,
        uint256 allInSystem,
        uint256 receiverAuthority
    );

    constructor(address _oracle) {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        oracle = _oracle;
        jobId = "0b0e0c3944a94c989515e2dd81087356";
        fee = 0.1 * 10**18; // (Varies by network and job)
    }

    /**
     * Initial request
     */
    function requestValidationData(
        string memory _jwtToken,
        string memory _jobId
    ) public {
        jobId = stringToBytes32(_jobId);
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(
            jobId,
            address(this),
            this.fulfill.selector
        );
        request.add("orgAddress", "2021-11-02");
        request.add("senderAddress", "12111");
        request.add("receiverAddress", "FL");
        request.add("jwtToken", _jwtToken);
        sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }

    /**
     * Callback function
     */
    function fulfill(
        bytes32 _requestId,
        uint256 _allInSystem,
        uint256 _isProject,
        uint256 _senderAuthority,
        uint256 _receiverAuthority
    ) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
        allInSystem = _allInSystem;
        isProject = _isProject;
        senderAuthority = _senderAuthority;
        receiverAuthority = _receiverAuthority;
        emit requestFulfilled(
            isProject,
            senderAuthority,
            allInSystem,
            receiverAuthority
        );
    }

    function stringToBytes32(string memory source)
        public
        pure
        returns (bytes32 result)
    {
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringTest = bytes(source);
        if (tempEmptyStringTest.length == 0) {
            return 0x0;
        }

        assembly {
            result := mload(add(source, 32))
        }
    }
}
```

And Here is how I defined my job in TOML format:

```
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "Pliant-Chian_Adapter_5"
contractAddress = "0xec5368C5C258412B8518AEeb6966FAE07d0fc545"
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type=ethabidecodelog
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type=cborparse data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type=bridge name="test_pliant-chain_adaptor" requestData="{\\"id\\":$(jobSpec.externalJobID),\\"data\\":{\\"orgAddress\\": $(decode_cbor.orgAddress),\\"senderAddress\\":$(decode_cbor.senderAddress),\\"receiverAddress\\": $(decode_cbor.receiverAddress),\\"jwtToken\\": $(decode_cbor.jwtToken)}}"]
    
    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch

    fetch -> parse_allInSystem
    fetch -> parse_isProject
    fetch -> parse_senderAuthority
    fetch -> parse_receiverAuthority
    
    parse_allInSystem               [type=jsonparse path="data,allInSystem" data="$(fetch)"]
    parse_isProject                 [type=jsonparse path="data,isProject" data="$(fetch)"]
    parse_senderAuthority           [type=jsonparse path="data,senderAuthority" data="$(fetch)"]
    parse_receiverAuthority         [type=jsonparse path="data,receiverAuthority" data="$(fetch)"]

    parse_allInSystem -> encode_mwr
    parse_isProject -> encode_mwr
    parse_senderAuthority -> encode_mwr
    parse_receiverAuthority -> encode_mwr

    encode_mwr   [type=ethabiencode abi="(bytes32 requestId, uint256 allInSystem, uint256 isProject, uint256 senderAuthority, uint256 receiverAuthority)" data="{ \\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"allInSystem\\": $(parse_allInSystem), \\"isProject\\": $(parse_isProject), \\"senderAuthority\\": $(parse_senderAuthority), \\"receiverAuthority\\": $(parse_receiverAuthority)}"]
    encode_tx    [type=ethabiencode
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes calldata data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_mwr)}"
                 ]
    submit_tx    [type=ethtx to="0xec5368C5C258412B8518AEeb6966FAE07d0fc545" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    encode_mwr -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
```

UPDATE:

I have used `sendChainlinkRequestTo()` to send request but according to `@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol`, only `sendOperatorRequestTo()` is said to to support multi-word response.

> ```
> /**
>    * @notice Creates a Chainlink request to the specified oracle address
>    * @dev This function supports multi-word response
>    * @dev Generates and stores a request ID, increments the local nonce, and uses `transferAndCall` to
>    * send LINK which creates a request on the target oracle contract.
>    * Emits ChainlinkRequested event.
>    * @param oracleAddress The address of the oracle for the request
>    * @param req The initialized Chainlink Request
>    * @param payment The amount of LINK to send for the request
>    * @return requestId The request ID
>    */
>   function sendOperatorRequestTo(
>     address oracleAddress,
>     Chainlink.Request memory req,
>     uint256 payment
>   )
> ```
>
> Blockquote

And when I use `sendOperatorRequestTo()`, the transaction is reverted with the following error:

> ```
> transact to ExternalAPIConsumer.requestValidationData errored: execution reverted: Must use whitelisted functions
> {
>   "originalError": {
>     "code": 3
>     "data": "0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e4d757374207573652077686974656c69737465642066756e6374696f6e730000"
>     "message": "execution reverted: Must use whitelisted functions"
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: This might be an issue with `1.0.0`, has this been opened on the chainlink github?

Comment: Can you try with `1.0.1`?

Comment: @PatrickCollins I have upgraded to 1.0.1 version and still get the same issue, But I think it may be because of I have upgraded the wrong: first I changed 1.0.0 in `~/chainlink/VERSION` to `1.0.1` and ran make install. I wonder whether its a correct way to upgrade.

Comment: I have also tried `go build -o chainlink ./core/` command to build current version

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK `oracle.sol` does not support "large responses" and hence won't support multi-word responses.

You need to switch to `operator.sol`, use `sendOperatorRequest(req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);` in your client contract and use `fulfillOracleRequest2` in your node's jobspec.

You can read more about the whole setup in [this blog post](https://ijonas.com/fetching-multiple-off-chain-values-from-a-smart-contract).

Answer (score 1):

In general you are trying to call a multi-Uint256 request but using `oracle.sol` as referenced in the `encode_tx` task in the `observerationSource` in the node `job-spec.toml` with `abi="fulfillOracleRequest(...)`. In general your error is sourced because `oracle.sol` does not support heavier data requirements such as multiple uint256 in a single request. See below for the code for `operator.sol`

If you would like to fix this issue you need to deploy `operator.sol`, whitelist your `["node_address"]` just as you did with oracle.sol, and replace the `contractAddress` in your `job-spec.toml` with the operator.sol contract address. Additionally in `encode_tx` task in the `observerationSource` in the node `job-spec.toml` specify `abi="fulfillOracleRequest2(...)` to properly reference `operator.sol`. Then finally switch out the oracle address pointed at in the test smart contract requesting the data to `operator.sol`

`operator.sol` is below:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT pragma solidity ^0.7.0;
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.7/Operator.sol";
```